# Use windows service to run a method every on second

Tags: c#, api, methods, timer, windows-services

Hi I wrote a method in my program which call a Rest Api and get some information.
I want to call every minute. I fill OnStart and OnStop and all  timer_Elapsed in which my method is there. I install my service and start it but It just run just for the first time and never repeat again would if anyone know the solution help me. In advanced I thanked you

On start  :

```
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
     {
        ///just for log to show program is working 
        ayandehBLL.Save_Log("Service started...", nameof(OnStart));


        if (timer == null)
        {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Interval = 3000;    //* 
            Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IntervalMinutes"]);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
```

---

```
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Enabled = false;
        ayandehBLL.Save_Log("Service stoped", nameof(OnStop));
        //WriteErrorLog("Test window service Stoped");
    }
  -----------------------------
    private void timer_Elapsed(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
      {
        var a = ayandehBLL.GetProductCode();
        ayandehBLL.Save_Log($"Request national code is {a}", "test");
        if (a != null)
        {
            Request_DOM request = new Request_DOM();
            request.ProductCode= a;
            try
            {
                var result = ayandehBLL.GetMyProductInfo(request);

                if (result != null)
                {
                    ayandehBLL.Save_Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result), nameof(OnStart));
                }
                else
                {
                    ayandehBLL.Save_Log("GetMyProductInfo() returned null", nameof(OnStart));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ayandehBLL.Save_Log(ex.Message.ToString(), "OnElapsedTime");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ayandehBLL.Save_Log("Request national code is null", "OnElapsedTime");
        }
        //WriteErrorLog("OnElapsedTime done");
    }
```

Comment: The way you configure your services is fine. However, I think there is an error during the after the first execution of the handler **timer_Elapsed**. Can you provide us with the log so we can find what's is the issue?

Comment: I dont have any error and I test it with windows form and it produce the data and I copy the code in button_click event in the time_elapsed.

Comment: when you check in your Services in windows is your services still running or it is stopped?

Answer (score 0):

The method triggered by a timer is being timed and run in a separate thread. If your main thread reaches the program end, the program will stop and the timer is discontinued. Therefore you have to capture the main thread before the end of the program in a loop where the program won't end until you want it to do so.

Comment: Using `while(true)` is a bad idea. That thread will just spin, sucking up power. You need need to hand control back to the OS. You could do a while loop with an `await Task.Delay` or something like that.

Comment: Well, I assume the program ends before the `timer.Elapsed` can trigger the method a second time. The timer configurations are correct so I don't know what else it could be. Have you debugged your program to see when it ends?

Comment: And yes you are right, `while(true)` is a very bad idea performance wise but it was simply an example of how to run the code indefinitely. I'm going to delete that part for future users. Point is, the program is not allowed to stop running or else the timer will terminate too.

Comment: @Despacito2 thank you for replying. I figure out the problem by adding write to file log in every line and my problem refer to my connection string.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about this possibility. Nice work figuring it out! Good luck with your project.